# Can Resource-specific consent (RSC) permissions be added to an app that is already added to a team?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have an existing Teams app, available on AppSource, with various app permissions granted.

I want to add the "TeamMember.Read.Group" permission via RCS, which is specified in the Teams app manifest. e.g.

```json
  "authorization": {
    "permissions": {
      "resourceSpecific": [
        {
          "name": "TeamMember.Read.Group",
          "type": "Application"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

In my development tenant, were I have the Teams app installed as a custom app via Teams Admin Centre, I can update the Teams app with the new manifest. However, the permission does not take effect in Teams that already have the app added, they appear to have the old version added. Removing and adding the app allows use of the new RSC permission in that same Team.

Can RSC permissions be updated for an app that a Team is already using, without removing the app?

Answer (score 0):

If you update the app manifest to include new RSC permissions, these permissions will not take effect in teams where the app is already installed.

To use the new RSC permissions, you would need to remove the app from the team and then add it back. This is because the consent for the app to access and modify a team's data is given when the app is added to the team.

Comment: I appreciate the response! For example, consider an app in production, installed to thousands of teams across many tenants. This app adds a new feature that requires a new RSC permission. This means thousands of individual team owners must be instructed by app developers to manually remove the app and add it again to access the new feature. Is there really no update process?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any available. To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in [Teams Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).